# How to return a JFrame inside a static method using a 'get' method

Tags: java, swing, class, jframe

I'm trying to return a `JFrame` into another method so that I can add/remove things from it, however I don't want to make a new `JFrame` each time I want to repaint. I understand that I need to repaint it in another class but 'getting' it into the class is what I don't understand, code:

```
public class TileFrame{
    public TileFrame {
    //all the usual jframe creation stuff here (not the issue)
    JButton[][] tiles = new JButton[4][4];
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
          for (int j=0; j<4; j++){
            tiles[i][j] = new JButton();
          }   
        }
    }
}
public class doSomethingWithTheTileFrame{ 
   public doSomethingWithTheTileFrame{
        retrievedTileFrame = getTileFrame();
        retrievedtileframe .....do stuff to this (this is already sorted)
   }

}
public static void main (String[] args) {
    TileFrame tileframe = new TileFrame();
    doSomethingWithTheTileFrame();

}
```

What I am asking is how do I retrieve this `tileframe` (a `JFrame`) without creating a new one each time in `doSomethingWithTheTileFrame`? Basically I'm asking how can I pass a `TileFrame` from the main  method back to the `doSomethingWithTileFrame`.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `What I am asking is how to I retrieve this tileframe (a JFrame)` and `//all the usual jframe creation stuff here (not the issue)`  --> is this JFrame declared as local variable (then the life would be easier for getter/setter e.i.), for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your TileFrame class extends JFrame. If so, why can't you pass the reference in like this?

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    TileFrame tileframe = new TileFrame();
    doSomethingWithTheTileFrame(tileframe );    
}
```